# Unbind listeners and rebind all later

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application, i am using a plugin (noUiSlider) and i want to make the tooltips editable by click.

My problem is, that the listeners from the plugin prevent the clicks on the tooltips. 
I want to unbind all listener, store them and rebind after an amount of time.

Something like (this won't work):

```
var listeners = $(element).unbind("click");
[...]
$(element).bind(listeners)
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: `unbind` returns `jQuery` object but not listeners. and `off` is preferable than `unbind` and use `$obj.data("events");` to achieve this

Comment: but $(obj).data("events") doesn't return anything. The events get bound with .on

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var element = $(selector), listeners = [];
// remove listeners
if ($._data(element[0], "events") !== undefined) {
  $.each($._data(element[0], "events"), function(key, value) {
    listeners.push([key, value[0].handler]);
    element.off(key);
  }); 
};
// add listeners
$.map(listeners, function(value) {
  element.on(value[0], value[1])
});
```

```js
var div = $("div"), listeners = [];
div.on("click dblclick mouseover", function(e) {
  console.log(e)
});

if ($._data(div[0], "events") !== undefined) {
  $.each($._data(div[0], "events"), function(key, value) {
    listeners.push([key, value[0].handler]);
    div.off(key);
  }); 
};

$("button").on("click", function(e) {
  $.map(listeners, function(value) {
    div.on(value[0], value[1])
  });
  div.text(function(_, text) {
    return text.replace(/off/, "on")
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>click dblclick mouseover (off)</div><button>click</button>
```